# ArcGIS JavaScript API, zoom to extent

Tags: gis, arcgis-js-api

I want to move the zoom to an extent.

I have this var:

```
var extentGeo = esri.geometry.webMercatorToGeographic(map.extent);
console.log('extentGeo', extentGeo);
// { cache: undefined
// spatialReference: {wkid: 4326}
// type: "extent"
// xmax: -70.60487747064096
// xmin: -70.67328452935668
// ymax: -33.42183884025852
// ymin: -33.48435589231657 }
```

Is there a way to move the map using those `extent.xmin`, `extent.ymin`, `extent.xmax`, and `extent.ymax` ?

I also have this function to zoom to points with zoom:

```
zoomToLocationLatLon = function(lat,lng,showPoint,zoom) {
            var pt = new Point(lng, lat);
            if (showPoint === true) addGraphic(pt);
            (zoom) ? zoom : zoom = 15;
            map.centerAndZoom(pt, zoom);
        }
```

I'm trying to use that function, but I don't know the zoom of the layer, I need a zoom ta fits the whole layer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [map.setExtent()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html#setextent) method:

```
var extentGeo = esri.geometry.webMercatorToGeographic(map.extent);
map.setExtent(extentGeo);
```